# Share QSS style with QWidget and QtQuick controls

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2, qtstylesheets

**Short version of question**

How to apply defined in resource file [QSS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) style to [QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) and [QtQuick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html) controls simultaneously?

**Full version of question**

There is some big project which is written using Qt. For customizing of appearance of controls is used Style Sheet defined in resource file. Now to the project added widget which use QtQuick control. By default control inherited from QWidget looks different with QtQuick controls. So question is: how to extend already existed StyleSheet on QtQuick controls with minimal changes of QtQuick code?

**Example**

[Here is complete example](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/31786449) for better describing of my question.
The project has following structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── MainWidget.cpp
├── MainWidget.h
├── QtWidget.cpp
├── QtWidget.h
├── QuickWidget.cpp
├── QuickWidget.h
└── resources
    ├── resources.qrc
    ├── style.qss
    └── widget.qml
```

`MainWidget` class defines (as expected) the main widget. At the begining `MainWidget` contains only one widget `QtWidget` which is inherited from `QWidget`. For customizing of appearance is used style sheet defined in `resources/style.qss`. Later `QuickWidget` class is added to the project. `QuickWidget` class v QtQuick control which is defined in file: `resources/widget.qml`. After building and launching application:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
./qqcs
```

the following window will be displayed:

[image]

I'm using:

- Qt 5.6;
- KUbuntu 15.10;
- Plasma Desctop.

Comment: Relevant question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430503/set-common-property-value-in-qml-such-as-qss